# Kinematics equations of motion find x position in 2D from height

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, velocity, software

I have a question and I thought of $2$ possible ways to answer it however the resulting answers are different which means I must be doing something wrong in my calculations.

All the below happens $2$ dimensionally.

I want to calculate the horizontal axis position of a ball at any given height value. The ball is thrown in a room with $2$ side walls (The left wall starts at the origin $(0,0)$).
There is no air resistance and collisions have no energy loss. I know the width/distance between the walls, I know the gravity force acting on the ball, I know the starting position as a point with an $x$ and $y$ value and I know the starting velocity.

**Attempt 1**

$$\text{Velocity}_X = (\cos(\text{angle}) * \text{Velocity}) $$

time to travel full width $ t_W = \text{WIDTH} / \text{Velocity}_X $

time first wall Collision $ t_F = (\text{WIDTH} - \text{Starting}_X) / \text{Velocity}_X $

time at given Height value Using Quadratic: $ s = (\text{given Height}) - \text{Starting}_Y $
$$t_h = \frac{-u + \sqrt{(u*u) + (2*a*s)} }{ a}$$

(integer is whole number) Subtract whole number leaving only fractional component
$$t = ((t_h / t_W) - (\text{integer})(t_h / t_W)) * t_W$$
X value at given height $s = \text{Velocity}_X * t$

**Attempt 2**

$$\text{Velocity}_Y = (\sin(\text{angle}) * \text{Velocity}) $$

$$ a = \text{Velocity}_y * \text{Velocity}_y $$
$$ b = 2.0f * \text{GRAVITY} * ( \text{Starting}_Y - (\text{givenHeight}) ) $$
$$ c = -\text{Velocity}_y * \text{GRAVITY} $$
time till returns starting height $ t_T = (a - b) / c $

total Distance Traveled $ s_T = \text{Velocity}_X * t_T $

Remove Starting Position $ s_T = s_T - \text{Starting}_X $

(integer is whole number) Subtract whole number leaving only fractional component
$$ \text{Result}_X = ((s_T / \text{WIDTH}) -(\text{integer})(s_T / \text{WIDTH})) * \text{WIDTH} $$

Any advice or insight welcome.

Comment: It is recommended you use math formatting with `$...$` instead of code for readability. See http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: @ja72 My apologies, I have changed to use the Math formatting.

Comment: Solve it without the walls, and then in end fit the $x$ value within the walls.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard projectile motion problem with the complication that the projectile collides elastically with vertical walls.
Assuming that the only force exerted on the projectile by the walls is in a direction which is normal to the walls then:

- the vertical velocity does not change,  and
- the horizontal velocity reverses direction but the magnitude stays
  the same.

So perform the standard projectile motion computation which will immediately give you the new $y$ position.
To find the new $x$ position between the walls proceed as in the following example.
If the projectile started at $x=1$ travelling in the increasing $x$ direction and the right hand wall is at $x=5$ then a calculated range  from $x=1$ of $7$ in the direction of increasing $x$ would indicate that the projectile travelled a distance $5-1=4$ before bouncing off the right hand wall and rebounded a distance $7-4=3$ thus finishing at $x=5-3=2$.

So your second method is the one to use.

Answer (score 0):

I can't read your both answers. but the answer to this question is :the initial velocity has two components horizontally and vertically. Horizontal component has no acceleration along it so it remains same but as gravity acts opposite to the vertical component it first decrease and after becoming zero again increase(as first the body goes up to a certain height and then come down).Thus distance along x is simply
velocity(horizontal component of initial velocity )multiplied by time .Then replace this time by time found out using the distance time relation(this  relation is uniform acceleration relation y equals  (1/2)gt2) for y axis (also note the distance covered along y is height h). So t is root 2h/g. put this in relation for x.

Comment: Were you unable to read both answers because of the formatting? I have changed to use the Math formatting as was suggested. Can you further explain your answer? As I understand it you find the total distance traveled horizontally as I have done in my second answer. How do you then get this as a distance value between the 2 walls when you take into account the collisions that have been happening as the object rose higher?